# How *File type can be passed as Reader type?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang. I saw a golang code like this:

```
file, err := os.Open("input.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
...
```

According to the documentation, `os.Open` returns `(*File, error)` type, and `bufio.NewScanner(r)`'s argument `r` is having `io.Reader` type.

On the code example above, variable `file` which is having type of `*File` (pointer to `File` type) can be passed to `bufio.NewScanner` method which the argument is expecting`io.Reader` type. How could that possible?

I checked the source code, the `File` type (https://golang.org/src/os/types.go?s=369:411#L6), and `io.Reader` type (https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=3303:3363#L67) seems are unrelated. So how could the parameter passing is possible?

Answer (score 3):

[`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is an `interface`, and [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) implements the interface. It's explained [in the Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) which I would highly recommend going through.

Comment: Is it because of [this line](https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=7374:7411#L97) (line 97) ? which is telling `*File` has implemented `Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)` method ?

Comment: Yes, that method fulfills the requirements of `io.Reader`.

Comment: Hmm ok, that's interesting, as someone who is coming from Java, I found the syntax design of the interface implementation in Go is a bit strange. I was expecting they are to be put in same place as the type definition.

Comment: I would definitely suggest reading the documentation and going through the tour. It will explain all the basic stuff without needing to ask on SO.

Comment: I would like to, but I was too curious that I want get the answer promptly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd still love to see this somewhere in the documentation easy to find. Still, when searching "Read" or "Reader" or "Open" on https://pkg.go.dev/std I don't see this link.